Select files in ranger using ranger
I am a bit confused about using regex in ranger (Arch Linux). I have a folder of files that look like this:
'sometexthere - I. - sometexthere'
'sometexthere - II. - sometexthere'
'sometexthere - III. - sometexthere'

I want to select only the files with II. or III. in the middle. I have seen this post, and I have tried to mark all the files using mark and regex like so:
:mark * [II.|III.]*

which should match 'any characters' + 'space' + 'II.' or 'III.' + any character.
However, it always selects all files including those with only one I.
Can anyone help me out here?
Cheers!

ChatGPT to the rescue:
:mark /*I\.|II\.
did the trick - I guess the dot has a special meaning here as well.

That... doesn't make sense. Are you sure it worked? What des /I mean? Why /? Is that the symbol for word boundary in ranger? And yes, the . means "any character".

pretty sure the / marks the beginning of a regex. Forgot the * though  - edited the answer

The / is used by many programs to indicate the beginnign of the pattern to be matched, yes, but then it is accompanied by a closing /. What you show would look for "0 or more /" which would match, of course, since no / is  "zero or more". Depending on the implementation details, the rest might look for "a I followed by either a . or another I, or it might look for "an I followed by a ., or two Is followed by a .".  But that isn't what you asked for. When you try it, doesn't this mark the I. file as well?
